# Does an extreme electric/magnetic field dilate time rates for a charged/magnetized clock?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, time-dilation

I want to know if general relativity (or any defined metric in general relativity) predicts any change for the clock rates in the electromagnetic fields (potentials) for some charged or magnetic clocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reissner–Nordström (RN) metric described the spacetime outside a charged and non-rotating spherical source. It has a static EM field, and an EM field has a stress energy tensor, so the metric is not a vacuum metric and hence it differs from the Schwarzschild spacetime without violating Birkhoff’s theorem.

In the RN spacetime the metric is different from the standard Schwarzschild spacetime. In particular, to your question it has different gravitational time dilation. $$\gamma=\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\left( 1- \frac{R_S}{r}+\frac{R_Q^2}{r^2}\right)^{-1/2}$$ where $R_S$ is a parameter that parameterizes the curvature from the mass and $R_Q$ parameterizes the curvature from the charge.

As you see, this differs from the standard Schwarzschild gravitational time dilation. The resulting time dilation applies to all clocks of any construction.

A clock that is also charged would have a force acting on it. Depending on the design of the clock, that force may distort the structure of the clock or otherwise result in a reading that deviates from the above equation. If so, that would not be described as additional time dilation, but as a deviation of such clocks from ideal behavior. In other words, such a clock would no longer be recording proper time.

Comment: Thanks @Dale. Therefore, you say that the electrical fields, contrary to the gravitational ones, cannot intrinsically affect the space-time curvature, can they?

Comment: They do affect the curvature. That is precisely what the $R_Q$ parameter describes. They impact curvature because EM fields have a stress energy tensor which is the source of curvature.

Comment: But, it seems to me that this effect has no clear relation to the *work* done on a charged clock ($q$) to move it inside the electric field of, say, a charged black hole ($Q$). Whereas, in the traditional Schwarzschild metric there is an interpretation for the gamma factor as the work done on the particle (clock) to move it between two points with different $g$-potentials. Indeed, I want to know if RN metric predicts the time dilation for a charged clock rewritable as a function of the *electrical* work done on the charged clock inside an electric field.

Comment: That is correct. The parameter is not interpretable in that manner. Depending on the sign of the charge the work could be either positive or negative, but the time dilation would be the same either way since it depends only on the square of $R_Q$. Also, an uncharged clock would have the same dilation, or a clock with double the charge. All would have the same additional time dilation from the charged source but different work.

Comment: One thing to add. The parameter is still interpretable at part of the potential energy of an uncharged particle. In other words, an uncharged particle will have a different gravitational PE due to the charge of the central mass